# Writing multiple lines to a new file in java?

Tags: java, windows

When I open the newly written file in jGRASP, it contains many lines of text. When I open the same text file in notepad, it contains one line of text with the same data. The transFile is just a variable for the name of the text file that I am making.

```
FileWriter f = new FileWriter(transFile, true);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(f);
out.write(someOutput + "\n");
out.close();
f.close();
```

I have changed the code to the following and it fixed the problem in notepad.

```
out.write(someOutput + "\r\n");
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Because that application follows the windows norm of using `\r\n` for EOL?

Comment: @BrianRoach And most notably *only* that norm. =)

Comment: @J.Steen - Yeah, I was editing my comment when you just commented :) It's worth noting that other, non-braindead applications may figure out a file is delimited with `\n`

Comment: @BrianRoach Agreed. Such as notepad++, already mentioned in an answer below. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\r\n is the windows carriage return, which is what notepad will recognize.  I'd suggest getting Notepad++ as it's just much much better.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way also:

```
public void appendLineToFile(String filename, String someOutput) {        
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;        
    try {            
        //Construct the BufferedWriter object
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));            
        //Start writing to the output stream
        bufferedWriter.append( someOutput );
        bufferedWriter.newLine();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        //Close the BufferedWriter
        try {
            if (bufferedWriter != null) {
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `BufferedWriter` has no such method - you need to use `newLine()`

Answer (score 1):

The default line separator for windows (historically) is `\r\n`. The windows "notepad" app *only* recognizes that separator.

Java actually knows the default line separator for the system it's running on and makes it available via the system property `line.separator`. In your code you could do:

```
...
out.write(someOutput);
out.newLine();
...
```

the `newLine()` method appends the system's line separator as defined in that property.